# returning null value from populated selectlist with DB data

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.0

I'm implementing asp.net core MVC project. In my controller class called ApiApplicant, Create method, I have 3 selectlists that its items should be populated from a table called APIApplicantHistory. My models and create method and view are implemented like following:

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;

      namespace CSDDashboard.Models
     {
      public partial class Apiapplicant
      {
        public Apiapplicant()
        {
            ApiApplicantHistory = new HashSet<ApiApplicantHistory>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ApiRequestDate { get; set; }
        public int? ApiRequestNo { get; set; }
        public int? Apiid { get; set; }
        public int? ApplicantId { get; set; }
        public int? GateId { get; set; }
        public string NocRequestDate { get; set; }
        public string NocRequestNo { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public virtual Api Api { get; set; }
        public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
        public virtual Gate Gate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApiApplicantHistory> ApiApplicantHistory { get; set; }
    }
}

     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;

     namespace CSDDashboard.Models
     {
     public partial class ApiApplicantHistory
     {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ApiApplicantId { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public int? SentResponseType { get; set; }
        public int? UnconfirmedReason { get; set; }
        public int LastReqStatus { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

           public virtual Apiapplicant ApiApplicant { get; set; }
           public virtual EntityType LastReqStatusNavigation { get; set; }
           public virtual EntityType SentResponseTypeNavigation { get; set; }
           public virtual EntityType UnconfirmedReasonNavigation { get; set; }
        }
       }


       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;

       namespace CSDDashboard.Models
       {
        public partial class EntityType
       {
        public EntityType()
        {
            ApiApplicantHistoryLastReqStatusNavigation = new HashSet<ApiApplicantHistory>();
            ApiApplicantHistorySentResponseTypeNavigation = new HashSet<ApiApplicantHistory>();
            ApiApplicantHistoryUnconfirmedReasonNavigation = new HashSet<ApiApplicantHistory>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EntityKey { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApiApplicantHistory> ApiApplicantHistoryLastReqStatusNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApiApplicantHistory> ApiApplicantHistorySentResponseTypeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApiApplicantHistory> ApiApplicantHistoryUnconfirmedReasonNavigation { get; set; }

    }
}


      using System;
      using System.Collections.Generic;
      using System.Linq;
      using System.Threading.Tasks;

      namespace CSDDashboard.Models
      {
      public class APIApplicantViewModel
      {
            public Apiapplicant apiApplicantvm { get; set; }

             public ApiApplicantHistory apiApplicantHistoryvm { get; set; }
       }
      }


       public class ApiapplicantsController : Controller
       {
        private readonly CSSDDashboardContext _context;

        public ApiapplicantsController(CSSDDashboardContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

       public IActionResult Create()
        {

            ViewData["sentResponseType"] = new SelectList(_context.EntityType.Where(g => g.EntityKey == "sentResponseType").ToList(), "ID", "name");
            ViewData["unconfirmedReason"] = new SelectList(_context.EntityType.Where(g => g.EntityKey == "unconfirmedReason").ToList(), "ID", "name");
            ViewData["lastReqStatus"] = new SelectList(_context.EntityType.Where(g => g.EntityKey == "lastRequestStatus").ToList(), "ID", "name");

            return View();

        }
       }
```

And a part of create view implementation:

```
     @model CSDDashboard.Models.APIApplicantViewModel

       @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "create";
       }
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4">
          <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="apiApplicantvm.GateId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="apiApplicantvm.GateId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GateId"></select>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="apiApplicantHistoryvm.SentResponseType" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="apiApplicantHistoryvm.SentResponseType" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.sentResponseType"></select>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="apiApplicantHistoryvm.UnconfirmedReason" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="apiApplicantHistoryvm.UnconfirmedReason" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.unconfirmedReason"></select>

       </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="apiApplicantHistoryvm.LastReqStatus" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="apiApplicantHistoryvm.LastReqStatus" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.lastReqStatus"></select>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
        </form>
       </div>
      </div>

       <div>
       <a asp-action="Index">Back</a>
       </div>

     @section Scripts {
      @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    }
```

In create method, all the viewData are filled with the correct related data but the problem is existing in Create view, after running the project an error like below is shown in Create page:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

After debugging the code I understand that In create view, apiApplicantvm is not null but apiApplicantHistoryvm returns null and the above error is because of that. I appreciate if anyone could tells me how to fix the problem.

Comment: could you please add your `OnModelCreating` from dbcontext?

Comment: `_context.EntityType.Where(g=>g.EntityKey=="sentResponseType").Include(x=>x.ApiApplicantHistoryLastReqStatusNavigation).ToList()` or

 on your modal creartingcreating
`protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);`
 for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: you have not used your declared ViewModel in the view

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please explain your answer more clearly?

Comment: can you try `var ent =_context.EntityType.Where(g=>g.EntityKey=="sentResponseType")
                    .Include(x=>x.ApiApplicantHistoryLastReqStatusNavigation).ToList()` in your create method and check respone for it?

Comment: I added var ent = _context.EntityType.Where(g => g.EntityKey == "sentResponseType").Include(x => x.ApiApplicantHistoryLastReqStatusNavigation).ToList(); in my create method in Controller and in view I wrote <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="apiApplicantHistoryvm.SentResponseType" class="control-label"></label> <select asp-for="apiApplicantHistoryvm.SentResponseType" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ent"></select>
            </div> after running the project and in Create page, I see a field "sentResponseType" but it isn't filled with related data

Answer (score 0):

I hope you would be using EF core as ORM because you are using `Asp.net core`.

To load related data in `EF core`.

It can be done in 2 ways  or **Lazy loading**

**Eager loading**

`_context.EntityType.Where(g=>g.EntityKey=="sentResponseType")
                    .Include(x=>x.ApiApplicantHistoryLastReqStatusNavigation).ToList()`

**OR**

**Lazy loading**
on your modal creating

`protected override void 
OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder .UseLazyLoadingProxies() .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);`

**OR**

on startup.cs of your core MVC project
Lazy loading example.

`.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(
    b => b.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
          .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));`

for more info learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the answers. I'm using EF core and I changed my code as what you suggested. I added  ViewData["sentResponseType"] = new SelectList(_context.EntityType.Where(g => g.EntityKey == "sentResponseType")
                    .Include(x => x.ApiApplicantHistoryLastReqStatusNavigation).ToList(), "ID", "name");

in my create method.

And my problem is here in Create view, in the below line there exists a null value in apiApplicantHistoryvm:

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. The problem was here in my code
ViewData["sentResponseType"] = new SelectList(_context.EntityType.Where(g => g.EntityKey == "sentResponseType").ToList(), "ID", "name");

I should use Id instead of ID according to my EntityType model.